# Is there any way to avoid audit recording of @Scheduled function actions in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, audit, hibernate-envers

We're implementing Envers in a project that has some scheduled tasks which manipulates database records. We don't want these actions to be recorded in audit tables, only the ones users do. Is there any way to set it up in Envers?

Comment: These two questions are related to what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456454/how-to-prevent-audit-on-insert-using-envers-4-hibernate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430885/can-i-make-a-particular-transaction-disable-auditing-using-envers

Comment: The easiest approach is to extend from the default listeners and register your own implementations in place of the default Envers ones, have your scheduler code set a thread-local variable that your listener implementations look for and skip the delegation to the super implementation if its set; otherwise its business as usual.  Once the per-entity listener callback feature is in play, they'll be much easier to handle on an entity-by-entity case.